# nspredicate with groupBy don't like predicate with nsdate compare

Tags: iphone, cocoa, core-data, nspredicate

This code:

```
    entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"PerDestinationsStat" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    //NSFetchedPropertyDescription *rateCodeDesc = [entity.propertiesByName objectForKey:@"rateCode"];
    [fetchRequest setPropertiesToGroupBy:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[entity.propertiesByName objectForKey:@"rateCode"],[entity.propertiesByName objectForKey:@"rateCountry"],[entity.propertiesByName objectForKey:@"rateSpecific"],[entity.propertiesByName objectForKey:@"ratePrice"],[entity.propertiesByName objectForKey:@"allCalls"],[entity.propertiesByName objectForKey:@"acd"],[entity.propertiesByName objectForKey:@"asr"],[entity.propertiesByName objectForKey:@"cost"],[entity.propertiesByName objectForKey:@"duration"],[entity.propertiesByName objectForKey:@"income"],[entity.propertiesByName objectForKey:@"succesefulCalls"],nil]];
    [fetchRequest setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
    [fetchRequest setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"rateCode",@"rateCountry",@"rateSpecific",@"ratePrice",@"allCalls",@"acd",@"asr",@"cost",@"duration",@"income",@"succesefulCalls",nil]];
    predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(perHourStat.dateFrom > %@) and (perHourStat.dateTo < %@) and (perHourStat.originator.company == %@)",from,to,selected];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
    fetchedObjects = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

find no objects, but if i using :

```
    predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@" (perHourStat.originator.company == %@)",selected];
```

object finded:

```
> Printing description of fetchedObjects: <_PFArray 0x100664fb0>(
> <PerHourStat: 0x101233810> (entity: PerHourStat; id: 0x10122f310
> <x-coredata://BBDDF3D7-EA50-4290-B03A-05349E74467E/PerHourStat/p1> ;
> data: {
>     acd = "0.03688591122627258";
>     allCalls = 3;
>     asr = 1;
>     cost = "0.1327892804145813";
>     dateFrom = "2013-02-11 21:00:00 +0000";
>     dateTo = "2013-02-11 21:59:59 +0000";
>     duration = "6.639464020729065";
>     income = "0.1991839206218719";
>     originator = "0x101236000 <x-coredata://BBDDF3D7-EA50-4290-B03A-05349E74467E/Originator/p1>";
>     perDestinationsStat = "<relationship fault: 0x104d2b9b0 'perDestinationsStat'>";
>     succesefulCalls = 3;
>     terminator = nil; })
```

from/to is matched dateFrom in finded object:

```
> description of from: 2013-02-11 22:00:00 +0000
> description of to: 2013-02-12 21:59:59 +0000
```

Comment: It looks like your date comparisons *should* fail, which would explain why no objects were found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing the same date `21:00` > `22:00`. This will clearly match 0 records.